# PLSQL Updating employee salary where department_id = 30 using cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sql-update

I need to update employee salary from department 30. all employees from department 30 will have 20% salary increase. I run into error while executing my code.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cur_emp
IS
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE department_id = 30;
rec_emp cur_emp%rowtype;
BEGIN
OPEN cur_emp;
LOOP
FETCH cur_emp INTO rec_emp;
IF rec_emp.department_id = 30 THEN
  UPDATE employees
  SET salary                = salary + (salary * 0.20)
  WHERE employee_id         = rec_emp.employee_id;
END IF;
EXIT
WHEN cur_emp%notfound;
 END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_emp;
END;
/
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: ORA-04098: trigger 'HR.TRIG_CHK_SAL' is invalid and failed re-validation
ORA-06512: at line 11

Comment: OK.  So there is a trigger named `TRIG_CHK_SAL` that isn't shown, presumably defined on the `employees` table, that has a syntax error.  The problem has nothing to do with your anonymous block.  It's an issue with that trigger.

Comment: then how can i update employee salary by 20% from dept=30 without encountering trig_chk?

Comment: i disabled the trig_chk_sal with- ALTER TRIGGER trig_chk_sal DISABLE;

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the task only by one DML statement rather than a code block, after commenting out the parts of the trigger's code which leads to the current issue or disabling it of course, such as

```
SQL> UPDATE employees
        SET salary = ROUND(salary * 1.2,2)
      WHERE department_id = 30;
     /

SQL> COMMIT;
```